# Map docker containers ports with nginx

Tags: docker, nginx

When a location is with root and another is with proxy_pass nginx does not work in the url /laravel. The response of this url is "404 Not Found".If I remove url location / and /moda, the url /laravel works. I do this, because I want map docker containers.

nginx.conf file :

```
 server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  local.monllar.com;
    location /laravel {
        root /var/www/local.monllar.com/public_html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:32768;
    }
    location /moda {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:2222/moda;
    }
```

}

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: the root location does not work。

Comment: Then the application that should listen on localhost:32768 is probably not reachable. Do you get any errors in the nginx log?

Comment: Please, edit your question and describe what does not work. What url's don't work, what http code you get, nginx logs...

Comment: See if you can debug using techniques I listed on http://tarunlalwani.com/post/how-to-debug-nginx-reverse-proxy-issues-php-fpm-gunicorn-uwsgi/

Comment: sorry for the confusion of the question. I have edited my question

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. This maps the ips of the docker containers to my local server names

nginx.conf file :

```
server 
{
    listen       80;
    server_name  local.monllar.com;

    location / {
        root /var/www/local.monllar.com/public_html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

}

server 
{
    listen       80;
    server_name  local.moda.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:2222/moda/;
    }

}

server 
{
    listen       80;
    server_name  local.laravel.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:32768;
    }

}
```

/private/etc/hosts file in Mac

```
127.0.0.1       local.monllar.com
127.0.0.1       local.moda.com
127.0.0.1       local.laravel.com
```